# I can't add items to HashMap after querying them from firebase android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to display the author and date of the last post published to a specific topic.

I have two collections, forum_topics and forum_posts. 
I iterate through all forum_topics and get the desired data put it into the HashMap topicData, then store the HashMap in ArrayList and display it through ListView, this works just fine.

But when I want to go through forum_posts(this query is nested inside forum_topics query) to get the latest post author and date I get the data but am unable to put it inside a HashMap topicData.
The query is okay because it gets the last author and post as logs show but they are not being put into the HashMap I don't know what seems to be the problem.

In the code, there is a comment pointing to the query that does get the data but doesn't add data to the hashmap.

Below is the code

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forum);
    addTopic = findViewById(R.id.addNewTopicBtn);
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);


    final ArrayList<Map> forumTopics = new ArrayList<>();

    final ListAdapter forumAdapter = new ForumAdapter(this, forumTopics);
    ListView forumListView = findViewById(R.id.ForumListView);
    forumListView.setEmptyView(empty);
    forumListView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);


    fStore.collection("forum_topics")
            .orderBy("date_published", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            final Map<String, Object> topicData = new HashMap<>();
                            // getting topic name and putting it to the topicData HashMap
                            topicData.put("topic_name", document.getId());
                            // getting topic author and putting it to the topicData HashMap
                            topicData.put("author", document.getString("author"));
                            // getting the date_published timestamp
                            Date date_published = document.getTimestamp("date_published").toDate();
                            // formatting the date to the desired 24hr format and putting it into the HashMap
                            topicData.put("date_published", DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", date_published).toString());
                            // getting the post_num and putting it to the topicData HashMap
                            topicData.put("post_num", document.get("post_num").toString());
                            Log.d(TAG, "Got the topic with name: " + document.getId());

// below is the problematic query that doesn't add data to HashMap
                            fStore.collection("forum_posts")
                                    .whereEqualTo("topic_name", document.getId())
                                    .orderBy("date_published", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                                    .limit(1)
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot post : task.getResult()) {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "got the last author " + post.getString("author"));
                                                    topicData.put("last_post_author", post.getString("author"));
                                                    Date date_published = post.getTimestamp("date_published").toDate();
                                                    String last_date_published = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", date_published).toString();
                                                    topicData.put("last_post_published", last_date_published);
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "got the last post " + last_date_published);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                            forumTopics.add(topicData);
                        }
                        // notifying the forumAdapter with data change
                        ((ArrayAdapter) forumAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    forumListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Map topicData = (Map) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String topic = (String) topicData.get("topic_name");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Forum.this, ForumTopic.class);
                    intent.putExtra("topic_name", topic);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
    );

    addTopic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Forum.this, ForumPostTopic.class));
        }
    });

}
```

I tried multiple things, doing the query outside the forum_topics query, iterating over ArrayList and then putting elements, I put the query into separate method, I even tried making another ArrayList iterating over the first one, getting the data from it, putting it back into another HashMap and adding it into the new ArrayList and updating adapter, but they all have failed.

Maybe I can get the desired data from forum_posts collection in another way, not by querying?

I would be grateful for any useful tips. I hope the question now is simplified as my previous one got closed.

Logs:

```
D/TAG: Got the topic with name: Some new topic in here
D/TAG: Got the topic with name: This is a new topic
D/TAG: Got the topic with name: 123
D/TAG: Got the topic with name: new topic
I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=79KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=48KB
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=47KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=47KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
D/TAG: got the last author Jo Do
D/TAG: got the last post 26-02-2020 10:42:46
    got the last author Jo Do
D/TAG: got the last post 26-02-2020 02:29:16
    got the last author Jo Do
D/TAG: got the last post 26-02-2020 11:01:25
D/TAG: got the last author Jo Do
D/TAG: got the last post 28-02-2020 11:19:34
```

Screenshot from firebase:

forum_topics:
[image: forum_topics]

forum_posts: from here I get the data in red but can't put it into HashMap
[image]

Screenshot from device:

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: I am using Firebase firestore and I am getting the data because logs show that, the problem is though data  it is just the case to put them into the HashMap that doesn't work because the data is there when you log it. I will add the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by notifying the forumAdapter after getting the callback from onComplete in second query.

As I debugged the app I saw that the code in the second query is executed after the first query finishes. It looked like the query was put on hold.

So the data was actually added to the HashMap, but adapter was unaware of new data added so it had to be notified twice, I thought it will be enough after the main query apparently it has to be notified each time the dataset change, that was a very valuable lesson and I new that solution was simple.

The code is bellow(I only post the code for the query that I thought wasn't working):

```
fStore.collection("forum_posts")
        .whereEqualTo("topic_name", document.getId())
        .orderBy("date_published", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .limit(1)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot post : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "got the last author " + post.getString("author"));
                        topicData.put("last_post_author", post.getString("author"));
                        Date date_published = post.getTimestamp("date_published").toDate();
                        String last_date_published = DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", date_published).toString();
                        topicData.put("last_post_published", last_date_published);
                        Log.d(TAG, "got the last post " + last_date_published);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
                // notifying the forumAdapter with data change
                ((ArrayAdapter) forumAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```